# Can you connect 2 networks from 2 different providers to 1 motherboard?

Tags: networking, router, lan, isp, wan

I was unhappy with the reliability of the broadband offered by my mobile service provider, but they've made it so there isn't a TV plan I'm happy with w/o broadband, so I'm still connected to them.
I upgraded to a gigabit connection from a small company. That leaves me with 2 routers:

- Huawei Echolife HG8245H providing 100 Mbit/s
- TP-Link AC1200 providing gigabit speed, connected to my PC's only LAN port.

I know the benefits would be marginal, but I'm wondering if I can use the speed of both together. If I can't sum their speeds, then I'd hope there's a way to make it so if 1 network goes down, the PC automatically switches to the other and/or faster one.

Comment: AFAIK, Link aggregation in this manner isn't natively possible in a Windows non-server edition _(if at all, it would likely be at the driver level with a PCIe card, as Windows' TCP/IP stack is relatively limited)_. Generally, this would be a full-fledged router OS [Sophos UTM, perhaps pFsense] or server OS feature [Windows Server, TrueNAS, etc.]. I've never used [Speedify](https://speedify.com/blog/combining-internet-connections/windows-10-channel-bonding-guide/), but it sounds interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Huawei router is connected to your computer via WiFi, while the
AC1200 is connected via the LAN, then the failback will be automatic,
once the AC1200 connection fails.

The operating system will usually prefer the LAN connection as its main
interface, as it's supposed to be faster than WiFi, but will use the
WiFi once it finds that internet is no longer available via the LAN.